# Draw a spline with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to simplify the code, that is to say not to use three times the command  \addplot[] ?

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{axis}[
 restrict x to domain=-5:9, xmax=9, xmin=-5,
 restrict y to domain=-3:4, ymax=4, ymin=-3,
 x=1cm,
 y=1cm,
 axis x line = middle,
 axis y line = middle,
 axis line style =ultra thick,
 major tick style=black,
 grid=both,
 major grid style=lightgray,
 minor grid style=lightgray,
 minor tick num=1,
 xtick={-5,...,8},
 ytick={-3,...,3},
 samples=1000,
 >=stealth,
 ]

\addplot[
patch,
red,
patch type=quadratic spline,
thick,
]
coordinates{
(-4,0) (0,1)(-2,-3) (-0.6,0) 
};

\addplot[
patch,
blue,
patch type=quadratic spline,
thick,
]
coordinates{
(0,1) (2,1)(1,2)(1.4,1.8)
};

\addplot[
patch,
green,
patch type=cubic spline,
thick,
]
coordinates{
(2,1) (7,0)(3,0.4)(5,0.1)
};

\node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (-4,0){};
\node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (7,0){};

\node[below left] at (axis cs:0,0) {$0$};
\node[below] at (axis cs:9.8,-0.1) {$x$};
\node[left] at (axis cs:-0.1,3.8) {$y$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You combine three curves. Between them spline functions doesn't work as you expected. If the curve can be one (in the same color), than just merge it into one.

Comment: You can do it _without_ an `\addplot` by using a `\draw` with `to[in=<angle>, out=<angle>, looseness=<values>]` operations.

Comment: @Tom Thank you for your answer. Nevertheless, I find to do too many tests to find the right entry and exit angles, but it might be me who does not know very well do it. Also, I found this in documentation `\draw [thick,red](-4,0)..controls(-2,-4)..(-0.5,0)..controls(0,1)..(0,1)..controls(1,2.3)..(2,1)..controls(2.8,0.1)..(7,0);`

Comment: @Fabrice: Oh right, I always forget about `..controls` as I rarely ever use it myself. Is the result you obtain with it satisfactory? If so, please don't hesitate to answer your own question, so that future visitors with a similar problem might profit from it!

Comment: @ Tom I posted an answer. Is it possible to see what you do ? Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to to generate a plot which is "close to" your screenshot, without requiring 100% accuracy. That sounds a lot like "make it smooth and ensure that it interpolates at some key points".

While this can be done using manually computed splines, it is cumbersome as you need to fiddle around with the angles at the intersections.

There is also an automatic solution which consists of two steps: first you generate the plot (on the entire domain, meaning you can use tikz's `smooth`er), second you compute intersections segements and draw them in the desired color. The whole approach works as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{axis}[
 xmax=9, xmin=-5,
 ymax=4, ymin=-3,
 x=1cm,
 y=1cm,
 axis x line = middle,
 axis y line = middle,
 axis line style =ultra thick,
 major tick style=black,
 grid=both,
 major grid style=lightgray,
 minor grid style=lightgray,
 minor tick num=1,
 xtick={-5,...,8},
 ytick={-3,...,3},
 >=stealth,
 clip=false,% <--- otherwise $x$ will be clipped
 ]

\addplot[smooth,
    draw=none,% <- this plot is INVISIBLE
    tension=0.6,
    name path=plot]
coordinates{
(-4,0) (-2,-3) %(-0.6,0) 
(0,1) (1,2) %(1.4,1.8) 
(2,1)(3,0.4)
(5,0.1) (7,0)
};

\path[name path=cut line] (-4,1) -- (10,1);

\draw[red,ultra thick,
   intersection segments={of=plot and cut line,sequence=L1}];

\draw[blue,ultra thick,
    intersection segments={of=plot and cut line,sequence=L2}];

\draw[green,ultra thick,
    intersection segments={of=plot and cut line,sequence=L3}];

\node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (-4,0){};
\node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (7,0){};

\node[below left] at (0,0) {$0$};
\node[below] at (9.8,-0.1) {$x$};
\node[left] at (-0.1,3.8) {$y$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You see that I combined you interpolation points into one `\addplot`. That plot uses tikz's `smooth` plot handler which results in a smooth transition and controls the degrees of freedom using some `tension` parameter. The `\addplot` has `draw=none, name path=plot`, i.e. it is remembered only, *not* drawn.

Then we have `\path[name path=cut line] (-4,1) -- (10,1);` which defines and names `cut line`.

Finally, there are three `\draw` instructions which defines colors for specific `intersection segments`. The instruction belongs to the `fillbetween` library shipped with `pgfplots`. The argument `of=plot and cut line` computes intersections of these two plots, and `sequence` allows to select individual items of the result: "L" is the 'th item of the Left argument in `of=left and right` and "R" is the 'th item of the right one (not used here).

Comment: Just curious: is `tension` documented? I couldn't find it in the `pgfplots` manual. I'm interested in how it works.

Comment: Hm. I suppose it is not. And it is a feature of `tikz`, not of `pgfplots`. I'll add a reference of it to the `pgfplots` manual since it should be mentioned, but the ownership is in the pgf manual.

Comment: regarding "interested in how it works": it makes no promises whatsoever. All that I ever understood is "it makes it smooth". It is unrelated to any kind of numerical interpolation scheme, though. I suspect it is more a "pretty graphical tool".

Comment: Ah, thanks. I should have thought to look in `tikz` manual. The explanation on p672 (in v3.01.a) makes some sense to me: "Sets the factor used by the curve plot handlers to determine the distance of the control points from the points they control."

Comment: @Christan First of all, I admire your work, and I who used PSTricks, I dropped pgfplots to use. Your response is complete and a little sharp, I will look closely. In terms of color, it was only to indicate the use of three times \ addplot, because the curve will be drawn in black.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, here's what you could do with `to[in=<angle>, out=<angle>, looseness=<value>]`. The major downside is that you have to guess and improve the values, so you might need a few iterations until the result is satisfactory.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
[   xmin=-4.5,
    xmax=7.5,
    ymin=-3.5,
    ymax=2.5, 
    x=1cm,
    y=1cm,
    domain=-4:7,
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = middle,
    axis line style =ultra thick,
    major tick style=black,
    grid=both,
    major grid style=lightgray,
    minor grid style=lightgray,
    minor tick num=1,
    xtick={-4,...,7},
    ytick={-3,...,2},
    samples=100,
    >=stealth,
]

    \draw[thick, red]
        (-4,0)  to[out=-80, in=180, looseness=0.6]
    (-2,-3) to[out=0, in=250, looseness=0.4]
    (-0.5,0) to[out=70, in=240, looseness=0.8]
    (0,1) to[out=60, in=180, looseness=0.7]
    (1,2) to[out=0, in=120, looseness=0.8]
    (2,1) to[out=300, in=180, looseness=0.5]
    (7,0);

    \node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (-4,0){};
    \node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (7,0){};

    \node[below left] at (0,0) {$0$};
    \node[above left] at (7.5,0) {$x$};
    \node[below right] at (0,2.5) {$y$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A solution with TikZ and `..controls` :

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw[step=1.0,lightgray,thin] (-6,-4) grid (9,4);

 \draw[ultra thick,->,>=stealth](-6,0)--(9,0);
 \draw[ultra thick,->,>=stealth](0,-4)--(0,4);


 \draw [thick,red](-4,0)..controls(-2,-4)..(-0.5,0)..controls(0,1)..(0,1)..controls(1,2.31)..(2,1)..controls(3.1,0.2)..(7,0);

 \draw [thick](1,0.1)--(1,-0.1);
 \draw [thick](-0.1,1)--(0.1,1);

 \node[below] at (1,0) {$1$};
 \node[left] at (0,1) {$1$};
 \node[below left] at (0,0) {$0$};

 \node[below] at (8.8,-0.1) {$x$};
 \node[left] at (-0.1,3.8) {$y$};

 \node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (-4,0){};
 \node[fill=black,circle,scale=0.4] at (7,0){};


 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Tom Thank you a lot. I understand the `in` or `out` parameter that indicates the angle which the tangent to the curve with the x-axis, but I do not understand the parameter `looseness`.

Comment: `looseness` determines how "wide" a curve can be. With a value of 0 it will be just a straight line, just like using `(A) --(B)`. I illustrated the effect of looseness e.g. in [this question](tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69216/increase-the-bending-distance-of-a-to-path-in-tikz/69253#69253)